# when saving a machine learning model does it save the patterns it found during training

Tags: machine-learning

A doubt popped in my head when saving a model does the model also contain the patterns it recognized when it was trained?

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning just tries to find the optimal mapping function between input and output.
In training, if you gave x and label as y machine learning model tries to create a function f(x) which gives y

While you save the model it only stores the mapping function.

This mapping function is made from the patterns found in the training.